# Prestashop Ajax Call Not Processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

The code was utilizing `require_once` and it wasn't executing, by removing these and debugging the problem was solved

Changed required to include_once so

`include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../init.php');`

are working, but I still cannot access database files

**old edit**
Ok so

```
`if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    echo('no ps ');`
```

is echoing "no" into the return call of my ajax call, I have tried require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'../mymodule.php'); and it gave me a internal server error 500 in the console.

Every type of require_once call I've tried has given the same error, including direct hardcoded directories, url links, different files, files in the same directory, files in c and I've had no luck.
**older EDIT**

Ok, $_GET is showing the data is correctly passed to the ajax, the require_once was not working, so the ajax.php was not executing at all.

However, now Tools::getValue is not working, I have not tried to edit the DB but I don't think it will work since Tools::getValue is causing an error

**END OF EDIT**

Here's my ajax call, where urlvariable is pointing to http://myserverladidah/ajax.php and there's a bunch of variables to go along with it ?data= (some data) &moreData= (some more data)

It's redirecting to the correct controller, so the page redirect is fine, but nothing is happening in the ajax.php, I've cut the ajax down to just writing a hard-coded statement to insert something into the database but there's nothing happening.

```
jQuery.get(urlvariable, function (data) {
            window.location = 'index.php?controller=backendadminpage';
        });
```

I've double checked the url that I'm calling, and all the variables are checking out, but I just can't get these javascript variables into the database.

Sorry it was insufficient information, I hope this helps
// more information

```
var x = myFunction.getX;
var y = myFunction.getY;
var z = myFunction.getZ;

var urlvariable = '{$server}/modules/mymodule/ajax.php?x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&z=' + z;
```

//ajax.php file

```
<?php
require_once('../myModule.php');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `ps_my_table` (`name`) VALUES (`a`)';
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```

//previously php file tried to get values using tools, but since nothing was happening I deleted the code and tried the above

ps_my_table (`name`) VALUES (`' . Tools::getValue['x'] .'`)';

//variables are dumping properly in javascript with

```
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

//outputting

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Nothing is happening in the code we cannot see of which we don't know how it is called... That's not very helpful, you need to narrow the problem down to the js or php and post the relevant code and dumps of variables.

Comment: Ok I added a bit more, I only omitted it because I did not think it would be useful, sorry

Comment: No problem! The output of your php script will be in the `data` variable in javascript so what happens if you comment out the redirect, just echo something in php and log that output to the console in javascript (or alert it...)?

Comment: I tried to alert (data) but it just said "data" so like jQuery.get(request, function (data) {
    alert(data);
   });

Comment: Also, you need to make sure you can send your variables through the url by encoding them correctly using `encodeURIComponent()` in js when you build your url.

Comment: so like var request = '?x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&z=' + z; request = encodeURIComponent(request); request = url + request; or do I have to encode all the data individually, I'm curious because I'm using javascript and an ajax call that is working on another server, but it's running on a blog. So all the data that the javascript is generating is being passed successfully on another server without any encoding changes.

Comment: You have to encode each value individually, if you encode the whole string, characters like `=` and `&` to separate variables and values will also be wrongly (in this case) encoded. And when you work with variables in javascript, you should try to do a `console.log(data)` as then you can see exactly in the console what it contains.

Comment: Updated it to say `jQuery.get(request, function (data) {
    alert("Data " + data);
   });` and added `echo ("hello")` to the php, it is alerting Data hello properly, I am going to test it echoing Tools::getValue['x']

Comment: yes, like I said I've run the variables through console.log(); individually, so they're all set correctly before they're passed.

When I called echo(Tools::getValue['x']); in the php I got a 500 server error on trying to alert ("data " + data);

Comment: @jeroen thank you, I have updated the problem as it has evolved, now I only need to access the database from here and it will be smooth sailing :)

Answer (score 0):

The code was utilizing `require_once` and it wasn't executing, by removing these and debugging the problem was solved.

The ajax script can successfully use $_GET to manipulate the data as required.